# Web Pop-up Child

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button (web) that has the following code below.  Basically, it inserts data , but this button uses a pop-up child. What I want is that after inserting the data, the popup window should be closed.

```
protected void Criar_Fornecedor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            AddItemToListFornecedores(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser);
            string tempurl = currentsiteurl + "/Lists/EntidadesFornecedores/AllItems.aspx";
            SPUtility.Redirect(tempurl, SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEndResponse, HttpContext.Current);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new SPException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your ASPX code, your button for example? We need to see the markup of "popup child". Are you using Modal Popup of Bootstrap? JQuerey?

Comment: OK,               <td>
                <input name="BTTfechar" type="button" id="BTT_Fechar" value="Sair" style="height: 27px; width: 145px" onclick="closeDialog()">
            </td>

Comment: name="BTTfechar", onclick="closeDialog()"... we need the markup for Criar_Fornecedor button, can you post ALL your ASPX page code?